# Identity of "the Greek rabbi" in the Raavad's gloss (Tum'at Met 17:3)

Tags: historical-figures, rishonim

In [the Raavad's gloss on Hilkhot Tum'at Met 17:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=10&hilchos=56&perek=17&halocha=3&hilite=), he mentions a scholar who (like the Rambam) also erred in his definition of בטח - as found in the Mishna, Ohalot 12:3. Where the Rambam thinks that a בטח was a protruding windowsill (and the Raavad thinks that it concerns the caulking of an oven), this other scholar thinks that it was a type of bath. He is referred to by the Raavad only asהרב היווני: the Greek rabbi. Does anybody know who he is referring to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the *Rivmats*, Rabbi Yitzchak Ben Malki Tzedek, from Siponto in Italy. A little more about him in the [Wikipedia entry about him](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99_%D7%A6%D7%93%D7%A7).

The following [source](http://www.massorti.com/IMG/pdf/liberman_tossefet_rishonim_3.pdf) helped me find him (top of page 126).